# How do I iterate through elements in Selenium and Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to get to the texts inside the `span` tags by iterating through the `li` list of this HTML:

```
<ol class="KambiBC-event-result__score-list">
    <li class="KambiBC-event-result__match">
        <span class="KambiBC-event-result__points">1</span>
        <span class="KambiBC-event-result__points">1</span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

but i am getting the error

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute
>   'find_element_by_class_name'

on my code:

```
meci = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-result__match')

for items in meci:

 scor = meci.find_element_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-result__points')


 print (scor.text)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not using items inside the loop. You loop should be

```
meci = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-result__match')

for items in meci:
    scor = items.find_element_by_class_name('KambiBC-event-result__points')
    print(scor.text)
```

`meci.find_element_by_class_name` should be `items.find_element_by_class_name`

**Update for Selenium 4**

As mentioned in this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69963351/8718701), the `find_element_by_*` methods are deprecated from Selenium 4 onwards. Therefore, the solution would need to be modified as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

meci = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'KambiBC-event-result__match')

for items in meci:
    scor = items.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'KambiBC-event-result__points')
    print(scor.text)
```

Comment: Well, do i fell stupid now, also how do i access only the second child?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second comment, all you need to do is add ":nth-child(2)" to the end of the class name.

The class 'KambiBC-event-result__points' would read 'KambiBC-event-result__points:nth-child(2)' to only access the second child.