# Unable to locate elements in Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I tried to use Selenium with Chrome, but I was unable to find elements on the page. I tried it with link text, XPath, and full XPath, but there was just one error and it wasn't clicking on the element.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
print(driver.title)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search']").click()
```

Output:

```
 UserWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  warnings.warn("find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead")
```

I'm using ChromeDriver 81.0.4044.69 and version 81.0.4044.113 of the browser.

Comment: @Pete The first code you gave worked fine but I am still getting the error.

Comment: @DipakBachhav Well it is partially resolved

Comment: i am asking you web driver not chrome driver and secondly find_element_by_* should not deprecated if you use latest stable version 3.141.59 of webdriver (https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/)

Comment: @DipakBachhav I used the command:                                                                                                                    from selenium import webdriverprint, print ("Selenium webdriver Version: %s" % (webdriver.__version__))                                           And the version was:  4.0.0a5

Comment: @DipakBachhav I downgraded the driver to 3.141.59 and it is working fine now, thank you 3000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your comment, you are using [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) version 4.0.0a5 which is not stable though. There is the potential that features may be added/removed between these releases. You may switch back to 3.141.59 and give it a try:

[image]

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe",chrome_options=chrome_options)
url = 'http://www.youtube.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//form[@id='search-form']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='search-input']//input")))

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()
actionChains.move_to_element(element).send_keys("Test",Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

**Note:** please add the below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 14):

This error message...

```
 UserWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  warnings.warn("find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead")
```

...implies that the *`find_element_by_*`* commands are now associated with a deprecation warning in the latest Selenium Python libraries.

This change is in line with the **Selenium 4 Release Candidate 1** [changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d6acda7c0254f9681574bf4078ff2001705bf940/py/CHANGES#L32) which mentions:

> Specify that the "find_element_by_* ..." warning is a deprecation warning (#9700)

---

### Solution

Instead of *`find_element_by_*`* you have to use *`find_element()`*. As an example:

> You need to add the following import:
>
> ```
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> ```

- Using *`xpath`*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search']").click()
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search']").click()
  ```

Likewise you also have to consider the following changes:

- Using `class_name`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_class_name("element_class_name")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "element_class_name")
  ```
- Using `id`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_id("element_id")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.ID, "element_id")
  ```
- Using `name`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_name("element_name")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "element_name")
  ```
- Using `link_text`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_link_text("element_link_text")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "element_link_text")
  ```
- Using `partial_link_text`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_partial_link_text("element_partial_link_text")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "element_partial_link_text")
  ```
- Using `tag_name`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_tag_name("element_tag_name")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "element_tag_name")
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  element = find_element_by_css_selector("element_css_selector")
  ```

  Needs be replaced with:

  ```
  element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css_selector")
  ```

---

### tl; dr

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- Pull Request: [Specify that the "find_element_by_* ..." warning is a deprecation warning](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/9700)
- Commit: [Specify that the "find_element_by_* ..." warning is a deprecation warning](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/9700/commits/a31dad45097c70b8f7162039be0108d040771810)

Comment: Thank you, just need to mention that you have to import By
[from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By]

Comment: @MhdO. Great catch, added the import

Comment: In case of replacing find_elements_by_tag_name don't forget the 's'. Use find_elements to get iterable as a result

Answer (score 0):

I changed the xpath of the search box to (there are multiple elements with id 'search'):
`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search']").click()`

I then ran your code and it worked with no errors or warnings. **Do this fix it for you?**

Also, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish overall, but if you want to search something then you don't need to click the search bar first, you could just do.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search']").send_keys("Your search query")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='search-icon-legacy']").click()
```

As for the warning:
 `"find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead"` 
I believe that is because selenium is wanting you to use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id='search']')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found something in the Selenium documentation. Try to use this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("search"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('search')
```

For more information, read [the documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html).

Answer (score 0):

It’s just because of the version.

```
pip install selenium==3.14.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Re *"It’s just because of the version"*: Can you [elaborate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69732879/edit)?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to first import the `By` from Selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[@id='search']')
```

This would work.

Comment: This seems to be a follow-up to *[Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python/61309062#61309062)* (function `find_element` does require that import (otherwise the result is '`E0602: Undefined variable 'By' (undefined-variable`)' (with Pylint)) and the `find_element` line is exactly the one from Peter's answer), not an answer to the question. Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.