# Warning while using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium

While finding tag or class in a html using selenium, I am getting the following warning:

```
<ipython-input-6-f7f8e8a9bbfc>:32: DeprecationWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  divTag = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('quote')
```

But find_elements() is also not working:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
```

Can someone help me in removing the warning?

Comment: How are you calling `find_elements`?

Comment: You can remove the warning by doing exactly what the message says: stop using `find_elements_by_class_name()` and use `find_elements()` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
divTag = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('quote')
```

Try using

```
divTag = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'quote')
```