# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'following.txt error accessing a file using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, filenotfounderror

I have a problem. I'm trying to learn how to coding bots with Selenium. Everything ok but I can't save the follower list I got from Instagram as a txt file. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
def getFollowing(self):
        self.browser.get(f"https://www.instagram.com/{self.username}")
        time.sleep(3)
        self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a").click()
        time.sleep(3)

        dialog = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[role=dialog] ul")
        followingCount = len(dialog.find_elements_by_css_selector("li"))

        print(f"First count: {followingCount}")

        action = webdriver.ActionChains(self.browser)

        while True:
            dialog.click()
            action.key_down(Keys.SPACE).key_up(Keys.SPACE).perform()

            newCount = len(dialog.find_elements_by_css_selector("li"))

            if followingCount != newCount:
                followingCount = newCount
                print(f"New count: {followingCount}")
                time.sleep(3)
            else:
                break

            following = dialog.find_elements_by_css_selector("li")

            followingList =[]
            i = 0
            for user in following:
                link = user.find_element_by_css_selector("a").get_attribute("href")
                followingList.append(link)
                i += 1
                if i == followingCount+1:
                    break

            with open("following.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
                for item in followingList:
                    file.write(item + "\n")
```

```
elif choice == 2:
        instagram.getFollowing()
        following = open("following.txt", "r")
        for i in following:
            print(i)
```

ENTER YOUR COISE: 2

```
c:\Users\murat\Desktop\Çalışmalarım\Programlama\Exercises\InstagramBOT\main.py:72: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='react-root']/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a").click()
c:\Users\murat\Desktop\Çalışmalarım\Programlama\Exercises\InstagramBOT\main.py:75: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  dialog = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div[role=dialog] ul")
C:\Users\murat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py:501: UserWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
  warnings.warn("find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead")
First count: 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\murat\Desktop\Çalışmalarım\Programlama\Exercises\InstagramBOT\main.py", line 162, in <module>
    following = open("following.txt", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'following.txt'
```

Comment: Do you have following.txt in your InstagramBOT directory?

Answer (score 1):

2 things

1. You are getting

   ```
   DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated
   ```

in order to resolve that, you should change all the

```
find_element_by_*
```

command to

```
find_element(By.XPATH, "XPATH")
```

or to By.CSS_SELECTOR, By.ID, etc.. depending upon your selector.

2. No such file

   ```
   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'following.txt
   ```

you are using this line of code

```
with open("following.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
```

you are giving

```
following.txt
```

and since it's not `full file path`, Python will look inside the current project from where you are running your program.

Probably it is not present in the current working directory.

Please make sure it is present, also if not in the current working directory then you should give full file path.

On a windows system, it'd be something like this :

```
D:/FolderName/following.txt
```

This is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) there is a minor and a major issue in your program as follows:

- [DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python/69963351#69963351) is a *DeprecationWarning*. You can find a detailed discussion about how to suppress it in [find_element_by_* commands are deprecated in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium/69875984#69875984)

---

This error message...

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'following.txt'
```

...implies that your program is unable to find the *file* `following.txt` in the current working directory i.e. within:

```
c:\Users\murat\Desktop\Çalışmalarım\Programlama\Exercises\InstagramBOT
```

---

### Solution

To address this error you can adopt any of the below two approaches:

- Ensure that the required text file *`following.txt`* is placed within *c:\Users\murat\Desktop\Çalışmalarım\Programlama\Exercises\InstagramBOT* sub-directory.
- You can also pass the absolute path of the required text file *`following.txt`* as follows:

  ```
  with open("c:/absolute_file_location/following.txt", "w", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
  ```