# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in python selenium code

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, selenium-chromedriver

HTML:

[image]

I have created a xpath

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//h4[contains(text(),"This weekend")]'))
```

But every time I'm getting

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

It seems it is not getting the xpath.

May be the xpath seems wrong.cananyone guide here

HTML:

```
<a class="css-t8q75u e19c3kf61" xpath="1"><div class="css-ekw2cu eh8fd9012"><div class="css-3ov7b7 eh8fd9011"><div class="css-95s8c1 eh8fd9010"><header class="css-1p61d40 eh8fd909">** are not unique 

<a class="css-t8q75u e19c3kf61" xpath="1"><div class="css-ekw2cu eh8fd9012"><div class="css-3ov7b7 eh8fd9011"><div class="css-95s8c1 eh8fd9010"><header class="css-1p61d40 eh8fd909"><span class="css-m74hjb e19c3kf60"><span class="icon css-1ih0xvs e1ouvt3m1"><svg aria-label="CalendarWeekend" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="1.414" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 32 32" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" class="css-1lisf4l e1ouvt3m0"><path d="M28 14v9a5.006 5.006 0 01-4.783 4.995L23 28H9a5.006 5.006 0 01-4.995-4.783L4 23v-9h24zm-4 3h-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v1a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 001-1v-1a1 1 0 00-1-1zm-5 0h-1a1 1 0 00-1 1v1a1 1 0 001 1h1a1 1 0 001-1v-1a1 1 0 00-1-1zm3-13a1 1 0 01.993.883L23 5v1a5.006 5.006 0 014.995 4.783L28 11v1H4v-1a5.006 5.006 0 014.783-4.995L9 6V5a1 1 0 011.993-.117L11 5v1h10V5a1 1 0 011-1z"></path></svg></span></span></header><h4 class="css-11rlpdz eh8fd905">This weekend</h4><div class="css-1bu4bq eh8fd908"><h5 class="css-j3w7e9 eh8fd904">Local events taking place on Friday, Saturday and Sunday</h5></div></div></div></div></a>
```

Comment: What is `text`? `text()` looks suspicious. That looks like you're trying to call a string.

Comment: <h4 class="css-11rlpdz eh8fd905" xpath="1">This weekend</h4> .. this is the text in the h4 class

Comment: I have just tried something very similar to this and get the same problem. Possible bug in the latest version of selenium (4.1.0) with Python 3.9.9?

Comment: @DarkKnight within `find_element()` you need to send a _By_ locator.

Comment: @DebanjanB **By.XPATH**

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Following the [DeprecationWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium/69875984#69875984) in [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) ...

```
DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
```

*`find_element_by_*`* commands are [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python/69963351#69963351) in the latest Selenium Python libraries and you have to use *`find_element()`* instead.

---

To send a *character sequence* to the text field you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

> > You need to add the following import:
> >
> > ```
> > from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> > ```

- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//h4[contains(text(),"This weekend")]')
  ```

Comment: OP is using find_element. That's what I also tried and observe the same error

Comment: @DarkKnight Double check the syntax and the position of `(` and `)`

Comment: I have checked it. Look at my answer. I think there's a bug somewhere

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer but confirmation of the OP's error. To be clear, this is selenium 4.1.0, Python 3.9.9, macOS 12.0.1

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
with webdriver.Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//h4[contains(text(),"This weekend")]'))
```

Obviously, I don't expect to find an h4 with "This weekend" as text. That's not the point. The error reported is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/G-DRIVE Thunderbolt 3/PythonStuff/Oct07.py", line 9, in 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH('//h4[contains(text(),"This weekend")]'))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

This looks like a bug to me

Comment: Hye I used (By.XPATH, '//h4[contains(text(),"This weekend")]' this syntax ans it worked

Comment: What versions are you using?