# What is the correct way in Python Selenium to send text in text field?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Is it correct in Python selenium to send text in text field?

```
mobile= browser.find_element(By.name("mobile")).sendkeys("0000000000")
mobile.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the variable `mobile` to be the return value of `sendkeys()`. Try this:

```
mobile= browser.find_element(By.name("mobile"))
mobile.sendkeys("0000000000")
mobile.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [DeprecationWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium/69875984#69875984) in [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) ...

```
DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
```

*`find_element_by_*`* commands are [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python/69963351#69963351) in the latest Selenium Python libraries and you have to use *`find_element()`* instead.

---

To send a *character sequence* to the text field you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

> > You need to add the following import:
> >
> > ```
> > from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> > ```

- Using *name*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.NAME, "mobile").send_keys("0000000000")
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='mobile']").send_keys("0000000000")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@name='mobile']").send_keys("0000000000")
  ```

---

Ideally to send a *character sequence* to the text field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *NAME*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "mobile"))).send_keys("0000000000")
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[name='mobile']"))).send_keys("0000000000")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@name='mobile']"))).send_keys("0000000000")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```