# 'module' object is not callable error using webdriver in Google Collab to web scrape a site

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, callable

I have been trying to web scraping hotel reviews but on multiple page jumps, the url of the webpage doesn't change. So I am using webdriver from selenium to work this out. But I cannot use it in google collab in the first place. Any quick help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
# install chromium, its driver, and selenium
!apt-get update
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
!pip install selenium
# set options to be headless, ..
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# open it, go to a website, and get results
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)

driver = webdriver.chrome()
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/hotels/highland-park-hotel-in-trivandrum-1383427384655815037/?hquery={%22ci%22:%2220211209%22,%22co%22:%2220211210%22,%22r%22:%221-2-0%22,%22ibp%22:%22v15%22}&hmd=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&cc=IN&reviewType=gi&vcid=3877384277955108166&srpFilters={%22type%22:[%22Hotel%22]}")
```

Error:
[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you issue the command:

```
!pip install selenium
```

by default it installs the latest [***Selenium 4.1.0***](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/1902fb87d8817b771764628ffe95266f3d82ee89/py/CHANGES#L1)

Initially this line of code:

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)
```

initiates the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) *Browsing Context*.

But the following line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.chrome()
```

is error prone as `chrome()` is a module and is not *callable* as in:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Hence you see the error:

```
'module' object is not callable
```

---

### Solution

The initial line initiates the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727887/what-is-benefit-of-using-chromedriver-over-webdriver-if-we-are-using-only-chrome/53744026#53744026) / *Chrome* combo but with two [*DeprecationWarning*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64717302/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-selenium-python/70099102#70099102) as:

- [*DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69918148/deprecationwarning-executable-path-has-been-deprecated-please-pass-in-a-servic/69918489#69918489)
- [*find_element_by** commands are deprecated in selenium_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69875125/find-element-by-commands-are-deprecated-in-selenium/69875984#69875984)

For the time being you can ignore the [*DeprecationWarning*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61308799/unable-to-locate-elements-in-selenium-python/69963351#69963351) but you need to remove the line of code:

```
driver = webdriver.chrome()
```

Comment: I am new to this. Didn't understand the solution part. What should I replace the driver = webdriver.Chrome() with so that it becomes callable?

Comment: Keep only `wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=options)` and remove `driver = webdriver.chrome()`

Comment: code = wd.get(url) 
  str(code) == "<Response [200]>"
on running it is coming false

Comment: @ankeetjena I'm not sure what you are trying to do next, my answer was to address the _'module' object is not callable_ error. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.